# Suggested Resources to Learn Web Collect Tracking Configuration

Tags: marketing-cloud

I would like to implement the web collect tracking code by myself, but I do not know what "dynamic code" implies and was wondering if someone could please provide me resources or point me in the right direction in regards to this. I tried searching through documentation and looking through google to determine what "dynamic code" meant.

Replace "INSERT_EMAIL_OR_UNIQUE_ID" with the dynamic code to get the customer ID. A customer ID is typically an email address or custom number unique to that customer.

Please help point me in the right direction, ie, what skills do I need, what is the knowledge gap, what resources can I consult to bridge that gap and successfully implement the code?

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic content refers to content that is not static but can change depending on certain variables. A First/Last Name are good examples or if you want to show different content based on a Region (US, AUS etc.).

Here is some documentation on [Personalisation Strings](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/) which you use to populate an email with subscriber attributes amongst other things. Basically you can just insert them into your HTML.

[Here is some documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/index.htm) of AMPscript which is the ideal way to create dynamic content in Marketing Cloud. It's quite straight forward and the learning curve is a lot lower than other scripting languages.

Hope this helps.

Comment: To clarify, I've put the personalization strings on my webpage (outside of the salesforce ecosystem) how will they render if they exist outside of the salesforce ecosystem?

Comment: If you use this <a href="RedirectTo(CloudPages(00000))"> in your email link (if you're landing page is in Cloud Pages) then the personalization strings should work the same way as in the email.

Comment: My pages are not in Cloud Pages to clarify, so would this not apply?

Comment: If they're in Microsites then you can use <a href="RedirectTo(MiscrositeURL(00000))">. If it's a landing page hosted externally then you'll need another scripting language as AMPscript won't work. Hope this helps.